# Return from method in each - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Following continues the each even when I hit the line with return. How do you return from a method from inside an $.each?

```
removeFromArray: function (text, arr) {
        $.each(arr, function (value, key) {
            if (key.text == text) {
                arr.splice(value, 1);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why no simple `for` loop? If `$` is jQuery then have a look at the documentation of [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for an answer.

Comment: It is. Just realized its just standard jquery. Thanks. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really recommended to use Vue with jQuery ([link](https://www.quora.com/How-bad-is-it-to-use-jQuery-with-Vue)), also, Vue tends not to play nice with jQuery plugins (works though, [link](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/)). This is only my personal preference, that I don't use jQuery with Vue at all, so here's what I suggest.

Method 1: map and indexOf (assuming duplicates exist in `arr`)

```
removeFromArray(text, arr) {
    let idx = arr
        .map((item)=>item.text)
        .indexOf(text)

    if (idx !== -1) {
        arr.splice(idx, 1)
    }
}
```

Method 2: Reduce (assuming duplicates do not exist in `arr`)

```
removeFromArray(text, arr) {
    arr = arr.filter((item) => item.text !== text)
}
```

Comment: `const idx = arr.findIndex(item => item.text === text);`

Comment: @Andreas yeah, totally, `findIndex` is better!

Comment: Not better, just a "shorter" way (if it is available)

Comment: Okay, clarification, https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-findindex